# Is 'efficate' a word in English?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, is-it-a-word

I routinely hear the word "efficate" being used.  For example, "The most powerful way to efficate a change in the system is to participate."

I do not find entries for this word in common English dictionaries, but I do not have an unabridged dictionary.

I have checked the OED (I'm not sure if it is considered unabridged), and it has no entry for "efficate".  It does have an entry for "efficiate", which is used in the same way.

Wordnik has an [entry](https://www.wordnik.com/words/efficate) for "efficate" with over 1800 hits, thus providing some evidence for the frequency of use.

I personally like the word and find the meaning very clear and obvious when others use it.

If it's not currently an "officially documented" word, perhaps its continued use will result in it being better documented.

Comment: Are you sure you are not thinking of *effect* or *effectuate*?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it just looks like an attempt to promote a non-standard term. Even OP's own link to Wordnik says *Sorry, no definitions found.* (It's not in the full OED, btw.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - no I'm not promoting anything (unless I get royalties).  The question is clearly written in the title, with relevant details provided in the text.  Lighten up.

Comment: @TimLymington - Great question.  I'm definitely not thinking of either word (nor hearing it incorrectly, to my knowledge), although I think the speakers may be using an evolutionary form of the word "effectuate".  That word would be used in the same manner.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: I'm not exactly spitting blood! You're welcome to like the "word" if you like. I could have closevoted as Primarily Opinion-based, but this one is *so* far away from being a valid word to most people that I thought I'd go a bit further. When I Google it, the first result is your linked "user proposal" to add it to Wordnik. The second is just a web crawler site, the third is a moribund Facebook page *Quahaha'ing so hard until you efficate* (probably s/b *defecate*), and the fourth is your own question here. Sorry, this bird will never fly.

Comment: ...and I think people who still use ***effectuate*** instead of ***effect*** are [at least a couple of centuries behind the times](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+effectuate+a%2Cto+effect+a&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20effectuate%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20effect%20a%3B%2Cc0) (and they were only ever a minority anyway).

Comment: Looks like this site is more about language nerds getting together and acting like bullies.  One would have hoped these nerds learned the right lessons from being bullied as children, but apparently not.  Now they apparently like to feel powerful by censoring others, such as by declaring an English language question as off-topic in an English language forum.  Sad.

Comment: LOL. This question just hit gold status (over 10,000 views) despite being closed by a tiny group of people.  The world determined it to be a helpful question, even if the overzealous censors didn't think so.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such word. It is not in the OED or any other dictionary I found: even your Wordnik reference says 'user-generated': and 1899 hits on the entire internet is so small a number as to be probably simple mistakes (or discussions like this).

Myself, I'm quite glad it doesn't exist, since it would be both barbaric and otiose.

Comment: Perhaps the usage finds favour with people who're just smart enough to know there *is* a difference, but not quite smart enough to know when to use ***effect*** and when to use ***affect***.

Comment: Barbaric and otiose?  Okay, I now understand the type of people who spend their days writing answers here...

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - But your conclusion about these people can only be spockulative.

Comment: @Erik Kowal - LOL!  That's meldtacularly funny!  ;-)

Comment: I thought efficate was the adjective form of efficacy.

Comment: The  OED does happen to mention a verb spelled *efficiate*; fortunately, it is now considered to be obsolete.