# What is the adjectival form of efficacy?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

The word *efficacy* is often used in the medical field. For example, a
paper might be on the *efficacy* of a treatment or a particular drug.
The word, of course, implies how *effectual* that treatment or drug is.

Because *effectual* is the adjectival form of effect, I figured
*efficacy* had an adjectival form. Perhaps *efficate*, however, to
my disappointment, [I've found that *efficate* is **not a *real* word**.](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/204696/39425)

Does *efficacy* have an adjectival form or is the only real option
*effectual*? Though *efficate* is **not a *real* word**, would it be well
understood if it were used in this sense? What are some other options I
might use that would be a suitable, real-word substitute for *efficate*?

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, that would work, but it doesn't carry with it the implication that there has been scientific study into how effective it is. Efficacy, on the other hand, means exactly that it has been scientifically studied.

Comment: I think the existence, meaning, and relevance of ***efficaciously*** are General Knowledge.

Comment: An efficacious approach would be to look up 'efficacy' and nearby entries in a dictionary.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Says the geek with 86,000 rep on an English Language and Usage site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I did check the Merriam Webster online. It did not list an adjective form.

Comment: @fredsbend: My closevote wasn't intended to imply "everyone knows that". The point is that *anyone who wants to know* can easily look it up. Plus it's part of basic English "derivational rules" that ***efficacy*** leads to ***efficacious***, which in turn leads to ***efficaciously*** - which can easily be double-checked using a dictionary by anyone isn't sure whether that's a "real" word or not. But I'm old enough to remember [Lily the Pink](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/s/scaffold/lily_the_pink.html), so I *do* know the words.

Comment: One can't easily look up the adjectival form of *efficacy* because half a dozen common dictionaries I easily checked do not have an adjectival form listed.

Comment: @CarSmack And checking the surrounding entries doesn't work for an online dictionary. Only the book, but who uses that anymore?

Comment: @fredsbend Perhaps, although the [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/efficacy) does give Nearby Words, one of which is *efficacious.* But even then, it doesn't say what part of speech it is.

Comment: AHDEL gives 'efficacious' as a relative of 'efficacy', and the part of speech, if not obvious from formal considerations, can also be checked at AHDEL.

Comment: @fredsbend It does if you choose the right one (TheFreeDictionary).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Effective*** is a common choice, or you may use the (slightly more highbrow) [***efficacious***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/efficacious):

> capable of or successful in producing an intended result; effective as a means, remedy, etc

I do not believe "*efficate*" would be well-understood.

Comment: Efficacious is a bit of a mouthful too. Why do you think efficate would not be well-understood? Remember, this is in a medical setting where the audience understands the meaning of efficacy.

Comment: @fredsbend As a stand-alone word, the "-ate" makes me suspect the word is a verb. I know there are many adjectives with that ending (e.g., *latinate*) but there are probably many more (and much more common) verbs with the ending: "celebrate", "hyphenate", "pontificate". I expect it to mean "*to perform* an effect". Perhaps I'd think differently if I saw it in context, though.

Comment: @fredsbend Also, The American Heritage Dictionary explicitly lists *efficacious* in [its entry on *efficacy*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/efficacy). And for whatever my personal experience is worth, when I hear *efficacious*, I assume the context is medical by default. (I am not a medical professional.)

Comment: If someone used the word "efficate" I'd point them to the room down the hallway.

Comment: A pubmed search for "efficacious" turns up about 40 thousand results. A search for "efficate" yields exactly 1. This supports the idea that -- even in a medical context -- efficate is an unusual term. (Or at least one that biomedical researchers don't like to include in abstracts.)

Comment: Efficacious it is. That you @CurtisH. That was the info I needed to convince me.

Comment: If you don't like "efficacious" because it is too long, use **good**.

Answer (score 8):

Conventionally, the adjectival form of efficacy is 'efficacious'. The adverb would be 'efficaciously'.